# ASP.Net Core 2 - Using Url.Action to generate url to web api behaves differently?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've used the helper Url.Action to pass relative URLs from MVC views to Typescript/Javascript classes before in full ASP.Net MVC with success. Here is an example, in a cshtml file:

```
<script>
 let vm = new VM('@Url.Action("Names", "api/Data")');
</script>
```

The Typescript class constructor is passed the following string in full ASP.Net: "/api/Data/Names", but in ASP.Net Core 2, the passed URL is "/api%2FData/Names", which is an invalid URL.  I can't figure out if this is intended or a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Url.Action(action, controller)

Specify the controller name, not the route, e.g...

`Url.Action("names", "data")`

And then on the controller itself you can do something like...

```
[Route("api/data")]
```

Comment: Ah-ha.  Seems to do it.  Thanks!